# How to BULK UPDATE SQL Schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-schema

I am attempting to update a specific schema for all the tables, procs, and views; however, I am receiving a permissions error and I've tried everything.

Can someone help show to the correct way to set the permissions for the query below to not receive the error below.

**Query**

```
    USE CAD

DECLARE @OldSchema VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @NewSchema VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)
SET @OldSchema = 'Storefront'
SET @NewSchema = 'CadType'

DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA  ['+ @OldSchema +'] TRANSFER [' + @NewSchema + '].[' + DbObjects.Name + '];' AS Cmd
    FROM sys.Objects DbObjects
    INNER JOIN sys.Schemas SysSchemas ON DbObjects.schema_id = SysSchemas.schema_id
    WHERE SysSchemas.Name = @OldSchema
    AND (DbObjects.Type IN ('U', 'P', 'V'))
OPEN tableCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO  @SQL
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM tableCursor INTO  @SQL
END
CLOSE tableCursor 
DEALLOCATE tableCursor 
PRINT '*** Finished ***'
```

**ERROR**

```
ALTER SCHEMA  [Storefront] TRANSFER [CadType].[proc_UpdateVertical];
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object 'proc_UpdateVertical', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
ALTER SCHEMA  [Storefront] TRANSFER [CadType].[proc_UpdateElevationQty];
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object 'proc_UpdateElevationQty', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
ALTER SCHEMA  [Storefront] TRANSFER [CadType].[proc_Update_Set_LeafIsActive];
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql :

> ALTER SCHEMA schema_name       TRANSFER [ entity_type :: ]
>   securable_name    [;]
>
> Arguments
>
> *schema_name* Is the name of a schema in the current database, **into which** the securable will be moved. Cannot be SYS or
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
>
> *securable_name* Is the one-part or two-part **name of a schema-contained securable to be moved** into the schema.

So you need

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA  ['+ @NewSchema +'] TRANSFER [' + @OldSchema + '].[' + DbObjects.Name + '];' AS Cmd
```

Comment: Glad I asked the question because I was under the impression that the Schema was being moved and that is not the case. It is the table that is being transferred not the schema. My problem was that I has yet to create a CadType Schema and set it to the logged in user. Almost embarrassed to admit that.